# Switch ZXing camera device to front camera Iphone with phone gap

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, zxing

I am trying to change the default camera scanner (Back camera) to the front camera

I think it will be around this code

```
AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
```

what is the best solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using `AVCaptureDevicePositionFront` instead.

Edit: (After some research I like the answer here a lot too) [Set front-facing camera in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795327/set-front-facing-camera-in-xcode)