# iPad Mini With Retina - iOS7 BarCode Scanning using Front Camera

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, barcode-scanner

Is it possible to do barcode scanning using iOS 7 iPad Mini With Retina - Front camera

When creating a AVCaptureDevice - where do I specify that I need to use the front facing camera

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
```

Comment: I think this answers your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795327/set-front-facing-camera-in-xcode

Comment: Any reason why the front camera can not scan barcodes but can scan QR codes easily

Comment: Does the front camera have autofocus? Is the front camera not as high a quality as the back?

Comment: I Suspect the issue is that the front camera creates a mirror image.  Not sure why QR code is impervious to mirror image but bar codes are not.

Comment: I think QR codes just look for the 3 boxes to get orientation. So it probably doesn't matter. I think there is a way to turn off the mirroring affect. I've seen it both ways before.