# Auto Focus UIImagePickerController before taking picture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

How can I make the `UIImagePickerController` auto focus before taking the picture? I have implemented a custom overlay and can't seem to figure out how to make it wait to focus before taking the picture.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, unfortunately, you cannot ensure that the `UIImagePickerController` focuses before the picture is taken.

You need to dive one level deeper into the AV Foundation Framework ([programming guide here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188)).

The `AVCaptureDevice` class has the `adjustingFocus` method, so you could ensure that that method returns `NO` before taking your image.

There's some example code in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10795327/143913) using `AVCaptureSession` with `AVCaptureDevice`.