# Switching from back to Front Facing Camera Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, camera

I am trying to access the front facing camera and I feel like I am messing something up. I have tried to access other questions, [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795327/set-front-facing-camera-in-xcode), but it didn't work out.

Here is my code that shows the back camera:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];


    AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice= [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSError *error;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:&error];

    if ([session canAddInput:deviceInput]) {
        [session addInput:deviceInput];
    }

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    [previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    CALayer *rootLayer = [[self view] layer];
    [rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    CGRect frame = self.frameForCapture.frame;

    [previewLayer setFrame: frame];

    [rootLayer insertSublayer:previewLayer atIndex:0];

    stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];

    [session startRunning];
```

from Apple Documentation that @urnotsam posted, I see:

```
AVCaptureDevicePosition
Constants to specify the position of a capture device.

typedef enum : NSInteger {
   AVCaptureDevicePositionUnspecified = 0,
   AVCaptureDevicePositionBack  = 1,
   AVCaptureDevicePositionFront = 2
} AVCaptureDevicePosition;
```

I tried to edit the code by putting in typedef above AVCaptureDevice and replacing defaultDeviceWithMediaType  with a 2 for the front camera. That did not work.

So the code is currently working for the default camera which is the back main but I am trying to get the app to open up to the front facing camera... Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: Have you looked at apples documentation on switching between input devices(front and back facing cameras) https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW4

Comment: What about that code isn't working?

Comment: @MikeS updated to explain what I am trying to do. updated to show what I found in the documentation but not able to link it together. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795327/set-front-facing-camera-in-xcode/10795573#10795573) in the question that you linked to is the right way to do this. Can you edit your question to show how you tried to implement that answer and explain what about it didn't work?